# uncaught Reference error: invalid left hand assignment

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
if ((value.length == 12) || (value.length == 9)) {
    if ((value.length == 12)) {

        if (value.substring(0, 2) = "048") { //this doesn't work in the execution
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    if ((value.length == 9)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `value.substring(0,2)=="048"`. That is your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need == like this.  you cant have a single = in an if statement

```
  if (value.substring(0,2)=="048"){
```

Comment: Should usually use `===` is JS.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are using the JS assignment operator. Typically `var a = 123;`

You want to be using `===` since it **doesn't do type coercion**. As opposed to == which does.

```
if (value.substring(0,2) === "048") {
    // etc
}
```